# Is Element in DOM after a lib is added / downloaded and executed, the promise way

Tags: javascript

Imagine: you are inserting a script dynamically to the DOM and execute it. This script might insert some DOM nodes. There was no way to find out if that particular element was added to the DOM. See the following code:

function:

```
testIfElemIsInDom : function(elem){
    return $.Deferred(function(def){
        // TEST MAX 20 TIMES IF THE ELEM IS IN THE DOM
        var maxTryes=20,
            actTryes=0;
        // ANOYNMOUS FUNCTION TO CALL IT SELF
        (function _find(){
            // IS ELEM IN THE DOME AND DID WE REACHED MAX TRYES?
            if ($(elem).length===0 && actTryes<=maxTryes){
                ysHelper.wait("100").then(function(){
                    actTryes++;
                    _find(elem);
                });
            }else{
                // IF THE ELEM IS IN THE DOM AND MAX TRYES ARE NOT REACHED - RESOLVE THE DEFERRER
                if (actTryes<maxTryes) {
                    def.resolve();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        }());
    });
}
```

function call:

```
ysHelper.testIfElemIsInDom("div#element").then(function(){
// do stuff
});
```

Do you see any way to improve this function? i am not really liking the 20 times try thing but the function cant run endlessly if something other did when wrong...

The ysHelper.wait function is just a setTimeout done with promises...

Use case for me is: I add a jquery plugin, let it download, execute and test if the element (that is created by the jQuery plugin) is in the DOM and then display a div with the generated content...

Comment: I would question why such a function is needed and solve it by *"fixing"* the script that isn't properly giving you an option to apply a callback function.

Comment: This might better be asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: **that's a different topic**, there are so many scripts that do different things and might not include such functions, i guess its all fine if you load these "plugins" in the first place but this is simply not smart if you design for mobile or just the KB size in general :)

Answer (score 1):

> any way to improve this function?

That `return false` doesn't make any sense in an asynchronous function. Instead, you should reject the promise.

Also, since you have your timeout already conventiently wrapped in a promise, there's no reason to use another deferred at all. All you have to do is promise chaining, which leads to a cleaner, more functional, recursive approach:

```
testIfElemIsInDom: function(sel, maxTries) {
    if (typeof maxTries != "number") maxTries = 20;

    var elem = $(sel);
    if (elem.length)
        return $.when(elem);
    else if (maxTries <= 0)
        return $.Deferred().reject(sel+" was not found");
    else
        return ysHelper.wait("100").then(function() {
            return ysHelper.testIfElemIsInDom(sel, maxTries-1);
        });
}
```

Comment: this looks quite nice, thanks for the input! (and yeah, the return false makes no sense)